# How do I render a view from a razor page handler?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a collection of items in which I need the user to be able to add and remove them without actually making a post. The page gets rendered with `2 items` by default. The user can then add and remove as they would like. Then, when they finish, there's a submit button that will trigger the post.

I can't seem to get my `EditorTemplate` to render. I keep getting a `500` error.

`Shared/EditorTemplates/MyObjectModel`

```
@model Models.Common.MyObjectModel

<div>
   <h5>User #@Model.UserId</h5>
</div>
<div>
    <select asp-for="@Model.UserType"
            asp-items="@(new SelectList((Dictionary<string, Models.Enums.UserTypes>)ViewData["MyUserTypes"],"Value","Key"))"></select>
</div>
```

I'm using an `Ajax` `GET` to call this handler:

```
 public IActionResult OnGetEmptyStopTemplate()
 {
      var viewDataBase = new ViewDataDictionary(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), 
                new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelStateDictionary())
      {
          { "MyUserTypes", UserTypes}
      };

      ViewDataDictionary<MyObjectModel> viewdata = new ViewDataDictionary<MyObjectModel>(viewDataBase , new MyObjectModel());
            return new PartialViewResult() { ViewName = "~/Shared/EditorTemplates/MyObjectModel", ViewData = viewdata };
 }
```

Comment: 500 means unhandled exception. Check the output window to see what's actually happening

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto It can't find the page for some reason. I just added ```Pages``` before ```Shared``` and it still couldn't find it. Am I doing this the right way or should I be returning a ViewResult?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Also, if you know, is there a cleaner way to pass a model to an ```EditorTemplate```? That's what I'm after, I'm just returning a ```PartialViewResult``` because I didn't know what else to return and I can't find anything else on it.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto As soon as I changed the return type to a ```ViewResult()```, it finds the file. Now I'm getting a ```value cannot be null``` error that I'll have to track down.

Comment: I think you are confused as to what the EditorTemplate is for, you may want to read [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/344224/asp-net-core-viewcomponent-vs-editortemplate-displaytemplate-vs-inject). I think you should be looking at a simple partial view (not sure what's the equivalent in Razor Pages though, although at this point I would be looking at MVC)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I think I'm using the right thing. Correct me if you think I'm wrong, but my user needs to be able to create a list of users. So, I have an editor template for a user. So I need to be able to have ajax call a handler to return me the html for the edit form of a user. That's not correct?

Comment: The thing is, the editor templates are supposed to be used by the `@Html.EditorFor` calls, not for being rendered as standalone views. That's why I suggested partial views

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Valid. So I guess I'd just create a ```_UserEditPartial``` view? Then, is there a cleaner way to return a partial view and pass a model in. Something like ```new PartialViewResult(model)```?

Comment: According to [the source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/release/2.2/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages/PageBase.cs#L1233) it should be as easy as `return Partial("viewName", model)`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Weird. It must've changed or something. That's not available when a page inherits from ```PageModel```.

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/release/2.2/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages/PageBase.cs#L1233) it should be the same

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I just figured out that's 2.2. I'm working with 2.1.

Comment: You should read up about Partial Views in Razor Pages: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/partial-pages